# Ajax.Pager not working in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I was using Ajax.Pager in MVC 2 which worked fine.Here is the code in the view

```
<%= Ajax.Pager(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = ViewData.Model.UpdateTargetId, OnBegin = "beginPagings", OnSuccess = "successPagings", OnFailure = "failurePaging" },
        ViewData.Model.PageSize, ViewData.Model.PageNumber, ViewData.Model.TotalItemCount, new { controller = ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"], action = ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"], Id = ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"], str = ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["str"] })%>
```

and this is the AJax link builder code

```
private MvcHtmlString GeneratePageLink(string linkText, int pageNumber)
        {
            var pageLinkValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(this.linkWithoutPageValuesDictionary);
            pageLinkValueDictionary.Add("page", pageNumber);

            return ajaxHelper.ActionLink(linkText, pageLinkValueDictionary["action"].ToString(), pageLinkValueDictionary, ajaxOptions);
        }
```

But now when I upgrade to MVC 4 this is not generating links as expected.

Here is the MVC 4 code I use in the view

```
@Ajax.Pager(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = Model.UpdateTargetId, OnBegin = "beginPagings", OnSuccess = "successPagings", OnFailure = "failurePaging" },
        Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount, new { controller = ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"], action = ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"], Id = ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"], str = ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["str"] })
```

But the link generated is like below and its no more a link. Its rendered as plain text.

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-begin="beginPagings" data-ajax-failure="failurePaging" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="successPagings" data-ajax-update="#divGrid" href="">2</a>
```

I came across [a article](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2011/04/26/howto-ajax-actionlink-asp-net-mvc-3/) which says its because of “unobtrusive Javascript”.
Am I missing something??

This issue may be linked to a [similar issue in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050145/html-encode-decode-c-sharp-mvc4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked by using

```
@Html.Raw()

@Html.Raw(Ajax.Pager(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = Model.UpdateTargetId, OnBegin = "beginPagings", OnSuccess = "successPagings", OnFailure = "failurePaging" },
        Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount, new { controller = ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"], action = ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"], Id = ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["id"], str = ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["str"] }))
```

Now the text is rendered as links..

[Justin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/779513/justin-pihony) answer helped me..Thanks Justin.