# HTML encode decode c# MVC4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, html

I am in a process of upgrading a c# MVC2 project into c# MVC4.

**Here is the scenario in MVC2**

Input string(from database)

```
   Model.text="<p>Hi<br>hello!<br>you there</p>"
```

Output (rendered in the view)
 rendered using

```
 <%=Model.text %>

Hi
hello!
you there
```

**Here is the scenario in MVC4**

Input string(from database)

```
   Model.text="<p>Hi<br>hello!<br>you there</p>"
```

Output (rendered in the view)
 rendered using

```
@Model.text

<p>Hi<br>hello!<br>you there</p>
```

I tried

```
@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.text) 
@HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Model.text)
```

Nothing helps...

I had a similar problem in MVC4 [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956992/ajax-pager-not-working-in-mvc4) (the ajax result is rendered with html tags not the actual html)

Is some of my settings troubling me??? or is that something to do with HTML 5 or am I missing anything in using MVC4.
Please help!!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.text)
```

Comment: Thanks Justin!! that helped..This also solved the issue in the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956992/ajax-pager-not-working-in-mvc4

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want your text get encoded, that text should be of type IHtmlString. String texts are encoded by default.

In your case,

```
Model.text = MvcHtmlString.Create("<p>Hi<br>hello!<br>you there</p>");
```

would do the trick as well.

Answer (score 1):

In controller side

```
viewbag.msg="hello";
```

in the html.cs razor view

```
@Html.Raw(viewbag.msg)
```