# HTML encode decode c# MVC4 for one record

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use a rich text editor to save in an .NET MVC 4 app, and that works, but I'm having trouble showing the formatted HTML elsewhere.

I was able to get @Html.Raw(Model.text) to work in a row of a grid doing this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {

   @Html.Raw(item.Body)
}
```

but not in a page without that loop:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Body) //commented out to do this instead:
@Html.Raw(model => model.Body)
```

That tells me "model" doesn't exist in that context. Anyone know how to do this?  I got that from here: [HTML encode decode c# MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050145/html-encode-decode-c-sharp-mvc4/15644818#15644818)

Comment: "That tells me "model" doesn't exist in that context." - so what's error you're getting?

Comment: Have you tried declaring the model at the top of your page? `@model namespace.to.yourModel`

Comment: @von the error is "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type".  The model is declared at the top with model TheNewSolution.Models.Advisory

Comment: That is odd as that error usually means you have a linq query and you did not reference `System.Linq`. Is `Body` a property of `Advisory` and is `Advisory` a single instance? If you do a breakpoint on `@Html.Raw(model => model.Body)`, can you see the html value of `Body`? Seems like you have a mix of error here. Please let us know where excatly the error is. In the view or in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my question with a workaround. The screen is showing only one record, and to show my "Body" field with HTML formatting, I added a line to the Details method:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
{
        Advisory advisory = db.Advisories.Find(id);
        if (advisory == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        //added this line for solution
        ViewBag.htmlBody = advisory.Body.ToString();

        return View(advisory);
    }
```

In my view, I then used this:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.htmlBody)
```

Not sure if it's the best way, but it works.